# Windows docker-compose gives no output

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, docker-toolbox

I'm using Docker Toolbox in my Windows 10 Home Edition.

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file and it was working good, but I did an update from Dell (a critical one in the BIOS) in my notebook and `docker-compose` command is not running anymore.

When I run `docker-compose up` command at Docker Quickstart Terminal, it gives me no output and doesn't run anything, it just releases the console cursor in the same second I run the command. I also tried `docker-compose logs` but it also gives me nothing.

I already tried to run Docker Quickstart Terminal as administrator, I tried to uninstall and install Docker Toolbox again, and I also deleted the default machine in VirtualBox to create it again, but the problem persists. And since I'm not able to see the logs I don't know what's the problem.

I'll appreciate any help.

P.S.: `docker` command is ok. When I run `docker ps` it gives me an output, but `docker-compose` doesn't.

Comment: What's the output of `docker-compose -v` ?

Comment: @DominicWehrmann the same behavior, no output. the console just releases the cursor after run any `docker-compose` command.

Comment: Can you check if you can run any container with 'pure' docker? `docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx` for example

Comment: Same problem here. Could it be related to some windows update?

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading the version of compose 1.19 https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.19.0

Comment: @DominicWehrmann yes, I can. `docker` command works fine.

Comment: Same thing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @alex-costa said.

The problem goes away if you [download the 1.19 version](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.19.0/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe) and replace the one at `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\`

Comment: This answer was hopeful because I was updating docker-compose on the wrong path. As a Unix user, I was not aware that the common Windows installation has installed a docker-compose and added it to my path.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. It appeared yesterday and there is no windows update in the last week in my computer...

**docker-compose -v** works intermittently...sometimes it responds, and sometimes it doesn't.